# values in PostMessage method

Tags: c#, powerpoint, postmessage, user32

I tried to get process of the PowerPoint by two diferent methods. Both working, but i can't send the key to inactive window.

I took by the Microsoft Spy ++ the values:
When I push the right arrow button, i see 3 logs. I get first one, values:

- keydown code is  0x0100
- wparam 00000027
- lparam 014D0001

I try to put it into PostMessege and doesn't work, then I try with SendMessage nothing happens too.

Then, I find in random code this line

```
 PostMessage(childofpower, 0x100, (IntPtr)27, (IntPtr)0);
```

and when I run it, The application sends probably ESC, because the full screen mode is  closed.

I can't find the reason why my values doesn't work. I'm sure that I'm sending the values to the right window, because the ESC button works, I dont know why with these values, but works..

Thx for any advice

Comment: When I put 13 instead of 27, power point shows next slide, but i can't find value for previous slide

Comment: Manually start a slide show then press F1 to see a list of the keystrokes the slideshow window supports.  Try P for Previous slide.

Comment: Thx for comment, I'm trying with values of these keys and still nothing happens :/

Comment: Problem solved in other way